# PHP Get URL stuck in cache

Tags: php, joomla

Currently have one page but utilizing the variable: site to read in the site id number

https://www.sagu.edu/admissions/som-sample-church?site=23faf53d-2daa-4acf-b427-d28529e79ce3

https://www.sagu.edu/admissions/som-sample-church?site=55671530-b73d-45e3-be1c-d5b80692ea8b

Notice that in both these examples, they're using different site ids:
55671530-b73d-45e3-be1c-d5b80692ea8b
23faf53d-2daa-4acf-b427-d28529e79ce3

Within the page is the following code.  Keep in mind I'm using a plugin for joomla so it interprets the "[[" as < and "]]" as >

Here's a snippet of the code that's showing:

```
$siteurl = $_GET["site"];
echo $siteurl;
echo "[[br]]";


echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
echo "[[br]]";
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
echo "[[br]]";
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo "[[br]]";
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
echo "[[br]]";
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo "[[br]]";
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
echo "[[br]]";
```

====================

So the odd thing about it is that on the intial link, it works perfectly.  On the second link, it still thinks its using the same parameters from the first link.  Meaning, that the php thinks the url on both links are both the same.

Trying to get the correct url so that I can parse it out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Re-order your plugin to be executed before the "System - Page Cache" plugin. This should solve the problem.